# @ReplaceWithMock not mocking using Springmockito-annotations

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, springmockito

I have a class which I am trying unit test.  I am trying to test it using Mockito, and to resolve the spring injection with mockito I am using Springockito and Springockito-annotations.

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class,
        locations = {"classpath:testApplication-context-EU.xml"})
public class RelatedSearchToHotUrlProcessorTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    RelatedSearchToHotUrlProcessor processor;

    @ReplaceWithMock
    private RestOperations restTemplate;


    @Test
    public void testGetCategoryFromIdWithNoStoredAlias() {
        Taxonomy mockTaxonomy = mock(Taxonomy.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        GraphType.Node mockNode = mock(GraphType.Node.class);
        when(restTemplate.getForObject(anyString(), eq(Taxonomy.class))).thenReturn(mockTaxonomy);
        when(mockTaxonomy
                .getRev()
                .get(0)
                .getCountry()
                .get(0)
                .getGraph()
                .getNodeOrAtom()
                .get(0)).thenReturn(mockNode);
        when(mockNode.getAlias()).thenReturn("mockalias");
        String categoryAlias = processor.getCategoryAliasFromId(13130L);
        assertEquals("mockalias", categoryAlias);
    }
}
```

If I remove the `@ReplaceWithMock` and the `private RestOperations restTemplate` lines then it makes the right call and the value can be validated as correct.  However, I want to mock the RestOperations object inside the processor, but using the @ReplaceWithMock makes the restTemplate variable null, causing it to fail.  I haven't been able to work out how to isolate this member and mock it.

Comment: Yes, I am getting a NullPointerException because the restTemplate object is null for the restTemplate.getForObject() call, but I was expecting it to be a mock object

Comment: try using @Autowired to inject

Comment: If you define `RelatedSearchToHotUrlProcessorset.setRestTemplate()` you can inject the mock yourself as part of your test, removing any potential issues with the `@ReplaceWithMock` annotation

Answer (score 2):

Was having a similar problem, I found that annotating with @WrapWithSpy or @ReplaceWithMock was not enough. That is to say the field in the test class was null. Adding the @Autowired annotation in addition to the springockito annotation as per Arasu's comment fixed the problem - although it does look weird...

```
@Autowired
@WrapWithSpy
private SomeBean someBean;
```

Comment: Should note that this is the documented behaviour as per https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations "If You want to verify some interactions, You can add @Autowired annotation to the field - so it gets injected."

Comment: An issue has been rasied with Springockito to potentially change this behaviour so as using these annotations will always autowire the mock/spy [Automatically autowire WrapWithSpy and ReplaceWithMock annotated fields](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/issue/14/automatically-autowire-wrapwithspy-and)

Comment: @JamesKennard link is dead